# How to extend a pytest base class and override a fixture

Tags: python, class, pytest, fixtures

I have a base test class that implements some tests that i want to re-use. Idea is to inherit from this class and override a fixture to provide necessary input data to the base class tests. Something like this:

```py
base_class.py
class TestBase:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def base_settings(self) -> dict:
        return None
    
    def test_settings(base_settings):
        assert base_settings["value_a"] > base_settings["value_b"]
```

```py
test_my_class.py
class TestMyClass(TestBase):
    # override the base_settings fixture in TestBase
    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def base_settings(self) -> dict:
        return {"value_a": 4, "value_b": 3}
}
```

When i now execute test_my_class.py I would expect the `test_settings` test to pass (value_a is greater than value_b) but instead it complains that base_settings is None -> fixture from base class is used instead of the one in TestMyClass. How can i fix this? I also tried passing parameters via `__init__` method but it seems like this is not supported in pytest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested in pytest 8.0.1 and it works the way you expect. **What might be happening is that pytest executes your `TestBase` by itself**, simply because you named it `Test...` and it therefore gets collected as any other test class.

In the following example 2 tests are run, with one failing as expected not because it gets `None` but because I set both `value_a` and `value_b` to `3` just to prove that the fixture was indeed overridden between individual test classes:

```py
import pytest


class Base:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def base_settings(self) -> dict:
        return None

    def test_settings(self, base_settings):
        assert base_settings["value_a"] > base_settings["value_b"]


class TestMyClassA(Base):
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def base_settings(self) -> dict:
        return {"value_a": 4, "value_b": 3}


class TestMyClassB(Base):
    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def base_settings(self) -> dict:
        return {"value_a": 3, "value_b": 3}
```

**Note:** I changed `scope` to `class` because it seems more logical but the original `module` should work as well.